# select from table with `with` statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:
[table with id, month, income](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmo3p.png)

If I want to sum for each month, I can do this:

```
 SELECT
     id,
     month,
     SUM(income) as month_income
 FROM test
 GROUP BY id, month
```

And I get this:
[table with id, month, income for month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWxUD.png)

Now I want to see the average income per month per user (note that some users have fewer available months).

I wanted to use this code:

```
with agg_month as (
    SELECT
        id,
        month,
        SUM(income) as month_income
    FROM test
    GROUP BY id, month
)
select
    id,
    AVG(month_income) as avg_per_month
from agg_month
GROUP BY id
;
```

But I get this error message:

> ```
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> 'agg_month as ( SELECT
>                     id,
>                     month,
>                     SUM(income) as mont' at line 1
> ```

Since the error message doesn't tell me much, I am a bit confused. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  CTE (WITH clause) is not available before MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2.  If your version is older, you can use a derived table instead.

Comment: Please next time post table info as TEXT, not as IMAGE.   On the question. the error always starts with the first word it does not expect, very often the error is between the word before that so in this piece `WITH `.   You are right about the help: this: [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=201&p=1&q=WITH+) is not much of a help, but this [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) is of more help 

Comment: I was using 5.7.37, so that explains it, thanks. I used goorm and that seems to be the standard version they use.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the output you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                month,
                SUM(income) as month_income,
                AVG(SUM(income)) OVER (PARTITION BY id)) as avg_per_month
FROM data GROUP BY id, month;
```

You can use nested aggregation function so you don't need to use a CTE which should also fasten your query. `.. OVER (PARTITION BY id)` groups the data by the values of column "id" without condensation to distinguishable ids. With the additional Keyword `DISTINCT` you can make sure not to ge rows with identical data (it is kind of like the result you get when using `GROUP By`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That looks like an interesting cos simple approach, but I get the error message `SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)` maybe I don't use the right SQL dialect/version?

Also note that there seems to be a closing bracket too many in your syntax, but I tried different variations of your command.

Comment: So I got your code working by adding a an opening bracket before the `PARTITION`. What I get is kind of what I was looking for. The only issue is: Each id apepars multiple times with the same value for `avg_per_month`, namely as many times as they had months. Is there a way to change it so that each id only appears once?

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT` should do the wished work. I have changed my previous suggestion and I hope it is working.